# Why can't I ping docker container within python?

Tags: python, docker, python-requests

I have a docker container made with the python docker library like so:

```
docker_client.containers.run(docker_image, detach=True, ports={'80/tcp': 83})
```

I start this in python and subsequently run a test request:

```
r = requests.get("http://localhost:83")
```

to which I get a Connection error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

When that happens, the application exits but the docker container is still running, so I try running `curl localhost:83` and that succeeds no problem.

What's going on here?
(This is on macos btw)

Comment: The docker container probably takes time to start up the webserver. Does the script wait long enough?

Comment: Just because you open the port doesn't mean the host you launched is listening on 80. And even if it is, you probably need to wait until it's booted and ready to make that request.

Comment: You guys were right. If one of you want to post it, I'll accept.

Comment: I don't like the idea of just adding a hard-coded sleep to the script, since there's no way to know if it's long enough. You should implement something more reliable, but I'm not sure how to do it, since I don't use Docker.

Comment: Fwiw, I wasn't actually using a hard coded sleep. I was doing a try request backoff on sending http gets until success.

Comment: Docker has a bit of documentation on how to sleep until a service is ready: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you run the container and don't wait for the service to comeup. You should wait for the service to get up. You can use something like below

```
def wait_net_service(server, port, timeout=None):
    """ Wait for network service to appear 
        @param timeout: in seconds, if None or 0 wait forever
        @return: True of False, if timeout is None may return only True or
                 throw unhandled network exception
    """
    import socket
    import errno

    s = socket.socket()
    if timeout:
        from time import time as now
        # time module is needed to calc timeout shared between two exceptions
        end = now() + timeout

    while True:
        try:
            if timeout:
                next_timeout = end - now()
                if next_timeout < 0:
                    return False
                else:
                    s.settimeout(next_timeout)

            s.connect((server, port))

        except socket.timeout, err:
            # this exception occurs only if timeout is set
            if timeout:
                return False

        except socket.error, err:
            # catch timeout exception from underlying network library
            # this one is different from socket.timeout
            if type(err.args) != tuple or err[0] != errno.ETIMEDOUT:
                raise
        else:
            s.close()
            return True
```

and then update your code to

```
docker_client.containers.run(docker_image, detach=True, ports={'80/tcp': 83})
wait_net_service("localhost", 83, 10)
r = requests.get("http://localhost:83")
```

PS: the code has been taken from https://code.activestate.com/recipes/576655-wait-for-network-service-to-appear/